# Chat Application working perfectly in local but not responding properly on server - signalr 2.2.1

Tags: c#, jquery, signalr

My SignalR chat application is working quite good in local machine, but when hosted on server few methods are are not responding at times. I searched for it number of times and found solution related to this.

- ConnectionTimeout
- DisconnectTimeout
- KeepAlive

Here's my code inside Hub

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    static List<User> connectedusers = new List<User>();
    string time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

    public void Connect(string Name)
    {
        var conId = Context.ConnectionId;
        if (Name != null)
        {
            connectedusers.Add(new User { ConId = conId, Name = Name });
        }
        if (connectedusers.Count > 1)
        {
            List<User> onlineUserlst = new List<User>();
            onlineUserlst = (from a in connectedusers
                             where a.ConId != conId
                             select a).ToList();
            Clients.Caller.alertOnlineToSelf(onlineUserlst, time);
            Clients.Others.alertOnlineOthers(Name, time,conId);
        }            
    }
}
```

Here, Name is the one user enters in prompt dialog while getting online and alertOnlineToSelf & alertOnlineOthers are the methods of clients where list of online users is appended in sidebar. The thing is here on server when some one gets online within 30 seconds, alertOnlineToSelf &  alertOnlineOthers methods are called but if same gets online after 30 seconds or more then others method is called for that person but caller method is called only for the person that got online within previous 30 seconds not for all those who are online eventhough i'm passing list of all the online users.

so i made this change in global.asax file

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(800000);
        GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600000);
        GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200000);
    ...
    }
```

Making these changes in startup file isn't showing effect at all so i added this configurations in global.asax. But this is not helping.
Please Reply if any one has some solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to give more information. What methods? When? What's happening? Errors?

Comment: P.S. I updated the Post. Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: Changing random timeouts to random values is never a good idea.

Comment: ok.. Thank you for your reply. and please guide me to right solution if you have one.  @Pawel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got solution for this Question!**

Actually above code was working perfectly fine,
i just changed the **hosted server**.

The difference between both the servers **was only of IIS versions**, my new hosting Server has **IIS 8.0 Express** & the older version was **IIS-7**, assuming it's **not supporting** the latest version of **signal-R**, i use Upgraded Version.